# apply style to scaffolded views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

Following is _form.html.erb generated during scaffolding.

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <!-- <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>-->
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I want to use the same view, but I want to apply style to it. I can see div classes "field" and "action", but I cannot apply style to it. I tried applying style from assets/stylesheets/posts.css. Neither can I find where css is originally applied to this form.

I am sorry, I am new to rails. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, you should have a css layout file at this path :

```
your_app/app/views/layouts/_stylesheets.html.erb
```

which is called from the main application layout :

```
your_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
```

In that file, you should see the following line :

```
<%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
```

That instruction calls the `_stylesheets.html.erb` layout file. In that file, you can find all the css imports. Ex :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'styles', :media => 'screen' %>
```

If you want reach the `styles.css` file, you can find it here :

```
your_app/public/stylesheets
```

Comment: Going with a "stylesheets" partial can be good for DRY code, but the `stlyesheet_link_tag` can also be included in the layout directly.

Comment: I totally agree. But, IMHO it's a good practice to separate the CSS calls. Of course, if you have only one call, then include it directly in the layout.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to include this line somewhere in your layout file, so that the CSS gets included in the page:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "my_css_file" %>
```

In your controller, you'll probably want to specify your layout. In the case of /views/layouts/my_layout.html.erb, you'll do something like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  layout :my_layout

  ...

end
```